# Is it risky to set config parameters during request? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

is it risky to set config parameters during request in Laravel?

I have multi-tenant application. During every request I set config parameter, database connection name, some parameters etc. Is this isolated for each request or can it affect other requests?

I found this in the **Laravel 4.2** documentation

> Configuration values that are set at run-time are only set for the current request, and will not be carried over to subsequent requests.

Is this information still valid?

I couldn't test this. I don't know how to test this scenario.

Comment: If you set it based on user input yes, if you have something like x static options based on a column in db, it is not risky. Is it best practice thou, probably not, but some sort of multi tenant database setup could probably require an approach like so.

Comment: Every request is "unique", the requests cannot "talk" to each other, not directly through PHP unless you use Redis, a database, and other stuff (and you want for that to answer back), else this is not like .NET where `static` is hold among ALL requests, PHP is per request. The only moment where you have to be careful is when you work with jobs/queues because the worker is executed continuosly and you could do wrong things